# Styling Outline in react-pdf

Tags: tableofcontents, outline, react-pdf

Is there a way to style the outline of the react-pdf module, according to the documentation, the Outline component has the props className, but I don't know how to use it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pass a classname to it you can target it after with css.

eg:

```
import "../styles.css";

export function ExampleeComponent() {

return (<Outline className="custom-outline" />);
}
```

styles.css

```
.custom-outline { color red; }
```